# Hide checkboxes in md-data-table when using single item selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I use single item selection with md-on-select in
[Material Design Data Table for Angular Material](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table)
and have checkboxes hidden? I think when we can select one item, checkboxes are no more needed and I want to hide them.

Single item selection achieved by selected item swap:

in row usage:

```
<tr md-row md-select="item" md-on-select="onSelect" ng-repeat="item in items"></tr>
```

onSelect method:

```
$scope.onSelect = function (item, key) {
  if($scope.selected.length >= 2) {
    $scope.selected.shift();
  }
}
```

[image]

When i use `md-row-select="false"` i lose ability to select single row.

**How can I hide checkboxes and still select single row?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Hide them like this:

```
md-checkbox .md-icon {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I asked about it author of md-data-table Daniel Nagy olmost a year ago, he gave me the same answer. I see I did't add this. xD

Comment: Cool! Sorry I'm all late I just ran into the same issue. Mine was that it was hidden but it was still showing the space. I realized If I wanted to hide the space it was taken up I had to use display: none instead.

Answer (score 1):

I created it some time ago.

Get git repo.

Edit files:mdSelect, mdHead

for hiding row checkbox: **mdSelect**

Add inside postLink function in mdSelect and mdHead

```
function noCheckbox() {
  if(attrs.mdNoCheckbox === 'true') {
    return true;
  }      
  return false;
}
```

and use it inside mdSelect enableSelection:

```
function enableSelection() {
  if(!noCheckbox()){
    element.prepend(createCheckbox());
  }

  if(autoSelect()) {
    element.on('click', toggle);
  }
}
```

Inside mdHead attachCheckbox:

```
function attachCheckbox() {
  ...
  if(!noCheckbox()){    
    children.eq(children.length - 1).prepend(createCheckBox());
  }
}
```

and add parameter to scope mdHead and mdSelect: `noCheckbox: '@mdNoCheckbox'`

Compile and it works with

```
<thead md-head md-no-checkbox ...
<tr md-row md-no-checkbox ...
```

and

```
<thead md-head md-no-checkbox="true" ...
<tr md-row md-no-checkbox="false ...
```

Single row selection by:

```
if (vm.options.singleRowSelect) {
      if (vm.selected.length >= 2) {
      vm.selected.shift();
   }
}
```

I will send pull request this weekend.